# JHipster/Java Spring Boot app wont' start when VS Code is running

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, jhipster

I have a Java Sprint Boot application that I have been developing for a while with JHipster and VS Code. Everything has been working well, I have been able to start and debug it no problem. Unfortunately, recently it started getting cantankerous and will no longer start if VS Code has the folder open. If VS Code is not running or does not have the folder open, ./mvnw starts it no problem and the app works.

However, if I try to run it from a Terminal in VS Code, or even from a separate Windows Terminal session while the folder is open in VS Code, it won't start due to Error: Could not find or load main class , when that class does indeed exist, or it starts but then it crashes due to unable to find the main class and/or some jar files

If I close VS Code then it works no problem. This just started happening, I think after VS Code was updated, and is very frustrating :(

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this and/or has it happened to anyone else?

Comment: I have found that the culprit is the Language Support for Java Extension version 1.4.0 (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java).. If I downgrade that to version 1.3.0 then the issue does not happen

Comment: I created this issue in the github vscode-java projeect for this:
https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2359